# What is GoogleSoftwareUpdateDaemon always running at 100% CPU

Tags: macos, google-chrome

The daemon running flat out all the time with no respite.

```
PID    COMMAND      %CPU      TIME     #TH    #WQ   #PORTS MEM    PURG   CMPRS  PGRP  PPID  STATE    BOOSTS              %CPU_ME %CPU_OTHRS
65896  GoogleSoftwa 99.7      61:14:03 7/1    5/1   94     9812K  0B     8164K  65896 1     running  *0[1]               0.00000 0.00000
```

Any suggestions on how to stop that from happening without disabling the daemon's essential function?

The paranoid half of me thinks they're using my spare CPU cycles to do their homework.  Of course, nobody would ever actually do that.  Right?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way... remove chrome (long term speaking is the best option).

If you still want to keep it, just make that google daemon check for new updates once each 4-7 days instead once each a few hours.

Keep away from chrome if you want some privacy

Comment: You say _just make that google daemon check for new updates once each 4-7 days instead once each a few hours_ - how?